# Java. Как долго создаются объекты, экономить?

Tags: java, производительность, memory, cpu, объекты

Очень часто в java создаются новые объекты для различных, и порой, примитивнейших целей. Например rowMapper, дто для перегонки с энтити, в лямбдах для того что бы просто Integer::sum и т.д. И живут, большинство, миллисекунды. Я знаю зачем это и сколько обьекты занимают места. Вопрос по производительности: стоит ли экономить на создании новых экземпляров и стараться обходиться без new где только можно? Или создание этих классов даже с дженериками, наследованием ничтожно и я просто параноик)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Объекты создаются очень быстро. Аллокация объекта в [TLAB](https://shipilev.net/jvm-anatomy-park/4-tlab-allocation/) осуществляется десятком инструкций процессора, почти бесплатно. А если ваш объект никогда не покидает метода, в котором создан, то виртуальная машина вообще не будет выделять для него память в куче, а [распределит его поля в стековом кадре](https://shipilev.net/jvm-anatomy-park/18-scalar-replacement/).

Про [аллокацию в TLAB](https://habr.com/post/332708/) и [скаляризацию](https://habr.com/company/jugru/blog/322348/) есть статьи и на русском.